# How to efficiently check if a ressource field is beeing updated when handling a PUT call

Tags: api, django-rest-framework, put, restful-architecture

Option 1 : send empty field if not updated on front. check if empty on back.

Option 2 : don't include field in request if not updated. check if field exists on back.

Option 3 : send a field value on front even if it is the same as the old value. check if request field is same as database existing value on back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The semantics of the `PUT` request are that the body completely represents the new state of the resource. The representation sent up by the client should completely overwrite the existing representation in the data layer.

At your choice, missing properties can either be defaulted to empty/null or can result in a `422 UNPROCESSABLE ENTITY` (or `400 BAD REQUEST` if you'are allergic to WebDAV). Any properties with an empty/null value would be set to empty/null in the data layer.

There's probably no need to check if the field is the same. Just clobber what's in the database.

If you want to update a subset of fields, you want either `PATCH`, `POST`, or micro-resources and `PUT`.

Comment: We are using put requests to update partially one field or any combination of fields, and that gives a lot of flexibility (one route for multiple user cases). If we do as suggested in your answer the API Client (an Angular SPA) will be obliged to get all fields values even if we need to update only one, such information is not always availables. Eg: Why do I need to get and send all user 15 fields if I need to update only the age

Comment: @user2080105 Doing that is a violation of the semantics of PUT as spelled out in https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-4.3.4. There are no internet police to stop you, but you should be aware you're disregarding the spec and losing the idempotence (https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-4.2.2) of PUT. You may want to consider the alternatives I suggested.